# Manually bringing up keyboard on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm making a hangman game in javascript and html. Currently I have it so the program just listens for keystrokes as the input.

```
document.onkeyup = function() {
        var guess = event.key;
```

I just discovered that on a mobile device, the keyboard won't pop up automatically. Is there anyway to get it to pop up manually if it detects that it's on a mobile device, without changing the code to take in prompts() instead of keystrokes?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make an input with display:none and focus on it on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on input element is what get Mobile to show keyboard.

So you should try to manually focus on some random element which if not needed can be hidden.

See [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

```
focusMethod = function getFocus() {           
  document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
}

<input type="text" id="myTextField" value="Text field.">
<p></p>
<button type="button" onclick="focusMethod()">Click me to focus on the text field!</button>
```